# Don't understand this problem with ranges::v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have the following code fragment using ranges::v3:

```
#include <range/v3/view/all.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>

struct EncodedValueDecoder: std::unordered_map<int, uint8_t> {
    using Base_t = std::unordered_map<int, uint8_t>;
    EncodedValueDecoder(int mask, const Base_t& values) :
            Base_t(values), mask_(mask == 0 ? std::numeric_limits<int>::max() : mask) {
    }

    std::string findAll(const int target) const {
        return *this | ranges::views::filter([&target, this](const typename Base_t::value_type& item) {
            return bitSet(item.first, target);
        }) | ranges::views::join(",") | ranges::to<std::string>();
    }
    int maskedValue(const int target) const {
        return static_cast<int>(target & mask_);
    }
    bool bitSet(const int bit, const int target) const {
        return bit & target & mask_;
    }
    int mask_;
};
```

I get the following errors

```
g++ -std=c++23 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wswitch-default -Wfloat-equal -c -pthread -Winvalid-pch -fmessage-length=0 -Wdouble-promotion -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wduplicated-branches -Wduplicated-cond -Wtrampolines -Wcast-qual -Wuseless-cast -Wsized-deallocation -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -fPIC -o src/main.o ../src/main.cpp 
../src/main.cpp: In member function ‘std::string EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const’:
../src/main.cpp:20:20: error: no match for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ and ‘ranges::views::view_closure<ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char [2]> > >’)
   18 |                 return *this | ranges::views::filter([&target, this](const typename Base_t::value_type& item) {
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >
   19 |                         return bitSet(item.first, target);
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |                 }) | ranges::views::join(",") | ranges::to<std::string>();
      |                 ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         |
      |                                         ranges::views::view_closure<ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char [2]> > >
In file included from /usr/include/range/v3/view/all.hpp:28,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:142:35: note: candidate: ‘template<class ViewFn, class Pipeable> constexpr concepts::return_t<ranges::views::view_closure<ranges::composed<Pipeable, ViewFn> >, typename std::enable_if<(is_pipeable_v<Pipeable> && concepts::detail::CPP_true_fn(concepts::detail::Nil{})), void>::type> ranges::views::view_closure_base_ns::operator|(ranges::views::view_closure<Fun>, Pipeable)’
  142 |             friend constexpr auto operator|(view_closure<ViewFn> vw, Pipeable pipe)
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:142:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/main.cpp:20:45: note:   ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ is not derived from ‘ranges::views::view_closure<Fun>’
   20 |                 }) | ranges::views::join(",") | ranges::to<std::string>();
      |                                             ^
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:127:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Rng, class ViewFn> constexpr concepts::return_t<Rng, typename std::enable_if<((range<Rng> && (! viewable_range<Rng>)) && concepts::detail::CPP_true_fn(concepts::detail::Nil{})), void>::type> ranges::views::view_closure_base_ns::operator|(Rng&&, const ranges::views::view_closure<ViewFn>&)’ (deleted)
  127 |             operator|(Rng &&, view_closure<ViewFn> const &) // ******* READ THIS ********
      |             ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:127:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Rng, class ViewFn> constexpr concepts::return_t<Rng, typename std::enable_if<((range<Rng> && (! viewable_range<Rng>)) && concepts::detail::CPP_true_fn(concepts::detail::Nil{})), void>::type> ranges::views::view_closure_base_ns::operator|(Rng&&, const ranges::views::view_closure<ViewFn>&) [with Rng = ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >; ViewFn = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char [2]> >]’:
../src/main.cpp:20:31:   required from here
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:127:13: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:117:35: note: candidate: ‘template<class Rng, class ViewFn>  requires (viewable_range<Rng>) && (invocable_view_closure<ViewFn, Rng>) constexpr auto ranges::views::view_closure_base_ns::operator|(Rng&&, ranges::views::view_closure<ViewFn>)’
  117 |             friend constexpr auto operator|(Rng && rng, view_closure<ViewFn> vw)
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:117:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:117:35: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/include/range/v3/range_fwd.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/view/all.hpp:20:
/usr/include/range/v3/functional/concepts.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Rng, class ViewFn>  requires (viewable_range<Rng>) && (invocable_view_closure<ViewFn, Rng>) constexpr auto ranges::views::view_closure_base_ns::operator|(Rng&&, ranges::views::view_closure<ViewFn>) [with Rng = ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >; ViewFn = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char [2]> >]’:
../src/main.cpp:20:31:   required from here
/usr/include/range/v3/functional/concepts.hpp:40:5:   required for the satisfaction of ‘invocable_requires_<Fun, Args ...>’ [with Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char[2]> >; Args = {ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll::._anon_127>}]
/usr/include/range/v3/functional/concepts.hpp:48:17:   required for the satisfaction of ‘invocable<ViewFn, Rng>’ [with ViewFn = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char[2]> >; Rng = ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll::._anon_127>]
/usr/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp:83:17:   required for the satisfaction of ‘invocable_view_closure<ViewFn, Rng>’ [with ViewFn = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char[2]> >; Rng = ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll::._anon_127>]
/usr/include/range/v3/functional/concepts.hpp:40:5:   in requirements with ‘Fun&& fn’ [with Args = {ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll::._anon_127>}; Fun = ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::join_base_fn, ranges::detail::reference_wrapper_<const char[2]> >]
/usr/include/range/v3/functional/concepts.hpp:40:5: note: the required expression ‘ranges::invoke((Fun&&)(fn), (declval<Args>)()...)’ is invalid
   40 |     CPP_requires(invocable_,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
In file included from /usr/include/meta/meta.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/view/all.hpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/cstddef:132:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::byte std::operator|(byte, byte)’
  132 |   operator|(byte __l, byte __r) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/cstddef:132:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ to ‘std::byte’
  132 |   operator|(byte __l, byte __r) noexcept
      |             ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/streambuf:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/iterator:66,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/range/access.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/view/all.hpp:22:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:87:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::_Ios_Fmtflags std::operator|(_Ios_Fmtflags, _Ios_Fmtflags)’
   87 |   operator|(_Ios_Fmtflags __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:87:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ to ‘std::_Ios_Fmtflags’
   87 |   operator|(_Ios_Fmtflags __a, _Ios_Fmtflags __b)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:130:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::_Ios_Openmode std::operator|(_Ios_Openmode, _Ios_Openmode)’
  130 |   operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:130:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ to ‘std::_Ios_Openmode’
  130 |   operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:170:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::_Ios_Iostate std::operator|(_Ios_Iostate, _Ios_Iostate)’
  170 |   operator|(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:170:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ to ‘std::_Ios_Iostate’
  170 |   operator|(_Ios_Iostate __a, _Ios_Iostate __b)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/shared_ptr_atomic.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.1.0/memory:78,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/utility/addressof.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/iterator/basic_iterator.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/iterator/reverse_iterator.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/range/v3/range/access.hpp:37:
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/atomic_base.h:98:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::memory_order std::operator|(memory_order, __memory_order_modifier)’
   98 |   operator|(memory_order __m, __memory_order_modifier __mod)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/atomic_base.h:98:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<const EncodedValueDecoder>, EncodedValueDecoder::findAll(int) const::<lambda(const std::unordered_map<int, unsigned char>::value_type&)> >’ to ‘std::memory_order’
   98 |   operator|(memory_order __m, __memory_order_modifier __mod)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
../src/main.cpp: In member function ‘int EncodedValueDecoder::maskedValue(int) const’:
../src/main.cpp:23:24: error: useless cast to type ‘int’ [-Werror=useless-cast]
   23 |                 return static_cast<int>(target & mask_);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

It appears to be complaining about the absence of a suitable overload for `operator|`. Given that I adapted this code from some examples I've seen in blogs dealing with ranges::v3, I've obviously misunderstood something. Can anyone point out my error?

Comment: Would be appreciated if you could link the blog where you copied the code

Comment: It wouldn't help. It's an amalgam of ideas and modifications.

Comment: After the filter, the value type of the range is still pair. You can't join two pairs with a string. Missing ranges::views::values?

Comment: What do you think the code should do? With an eye toward this goal, why you think the syntax should be correct?

Comment: @JaMit Thank you! Really! Thank you. I couldn't see my logic error. You asked the pertinent question and I see my own error. The code I posted is nonsense. No wonder it wouldn't compile. Once more, I'm enormously grateful.

Answer (score -1):

The code I've posted is nonsense which is why it wouldn't compile. Kudos to JaMiT. If I could find a way to award a gold star, I would.